# Create goroutine and set maximum goroutines

Tags: go

I'm learning Golang and I have some difficulties. I already researched Google, but no progress.

I made a code that check RTT via ICMP of several servers.

It has this struct:

```
type Server struct {
    id  uint
    ip  string
    rtt time.Duration
}
```

And it has a slice (Is it an array?) that contains several servers.
For each server in this slice I call function getRTT that returns the RTT then I store it on `Server.rtt` because after the for loop, I want to print all servers and their respectives RTT.

```
for _, server := range servers {
    server.rtt = getRTT(server.ip) / time.Millisecond
}
fmt.Println(servers)
```

The problem it's sync, so send one by one "ping". I want to make this async and limit the maximum goroutines. Example: Call 20 getRTT at once.

I'm reading about goroutines, maxgroup, channel, but I haven't got it so far.

Comment: Where is worker func? Where result is stored?

Comment: Ok! I will continue researching about this because it isn't clear for me. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

There are many patterns in Go to set a threshold for goroutines. One of my favorites is using the pipeline. In the pipeline pattern, you create a set of running goroutine and pass a structure to them as a work.

The following code is an illustrative example for pipelines. Please note that you must provide a synchronous way to waiting for goroutines to terminate for example using [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type handler struct {
        workStream chan int
}

func (h handler) handle() {
        for w := range h.workStream {
                fmt.Printf("do some work with %d\n", w)
        }
}

func main() {
        h := handler{
                workStream: make(chan int),
        }

        // run goroutines as much as you want
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
                go h.handle()
        }

        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
                h.workStream <- i
        }

        close(h.workStream) // by closing this channel all goroutines all killed

        // TODO: wait for all goroutines to die
}
```

Comment: Has it only one channel, right? This channel works for 5 goroutines?

Comment: You can think of the channel as a queue here - each worker takes the top thing off the queue, so yeah, only need one

Answer (score 1):

Start 20 goroutines to do the work.  Distribute work to those goroutines using a channel.  Wait for the goroutines to complete.

```
// c is channel for sending *Server values to worker goroutines.
c := make(chan *Server)

// Start worker goroutines. Each goroutine receives 
// values from c in a loop. The loop breaks when c
// is closed.
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
       for server := range c {
           server.rtt = getRTT(server.ip)
       }
       wg.Done()
    }()
}

// Feed work to the goroutines.
for _, server := range servers {
    c <- server
}

// Close channel to cause workers to break out of 
// for loop.
close(c)

// Wait for the workers to complete.
wg.Wait()

fmt.Println(servers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a simple count semaphore for this, combined with a sync.WaitGroup to ensure completion as @Parham Alvani suggests. (note that @Parham Alvani's solution is at least equally correct as this one)

(some explanation  - we make a channel with a buffer - the buffer size becomes the amount of allowed concurrent executions of the goroutine. Each goroutine puts something in the channel, then reads it back out. In the case of the code below, the fifth time, the goroutine is blocked adding to the channel until another goroutine takes something out of the channel.)

I also made the 'getRTT' function instead work on a pointer to a server, as we are munging the receiver here.

playground here:
https://play.golang.org/p/8Rmp0kHoNFB

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
    "math/rand"
)


type Server struct {
    id  uint
    ip  string
    rtt time.Duration
}


func (s *Server) setRTT()  {  
    fmt.Printf("setting rtt for id %d\n", s.id) 
    // do something that takes a while
    sleepyTime := time.Second * time.Duration(rand.Intn(5))
    time.Sleep(sleepyTime)
    s.rtt = sleepyTime
}

func main() {

    servers := []Server{
       {1,"10.10.10.0",0},
       {2,"10.10.10.1",0},
       {3,"10.10.10.2",0},
       {4,"10.10.10.3",0},
       {5,"10.10.10.4",0},
       {6,"10.10.10.5",0},
       {7,"10.10.10.0",0},
       {8,"10.10.10.1",0},
       {9,"10.10.10.2",0},
       {10,"10.10.10.3",0},
       {11,"10.10.10.4",0},
       {12,"10.10.10.5",0},
       {13,"10.10.10.0",0},
       {14,"10.10.10.1",0},
       {15,"10.10.10.2",0},
       {16,"10.10.10.3",0},

    }
    semaphore := make(chan struct{}, 4) // limit concurrency simply, you likely want a larger number than 4 here
    var wg sync.WaitGroup // necessary to ensure we complete everything - otherwise main will exit before we are done

    wg.Add(len(servers)) 

    for i := range servers {
        go func(s *Server) {
            defer wg.Done()
            semaphore <- struct{}{} // put something in channel, will block when > 4
            defer func() { <-semaphore }() // remove something from channel as this goroutine completes, allowing another goroutine to continue
            s.setRTT() 
        }(&servers[i])
    }
    wg.Wait() // wait for it!
    fmt.Println(servers)
}
```

example output:

```
setting rtt for id 16
setting rtt for id 1
setting rtt for id 2
setting rtt for id 3
setting rtt for id 4
setting rtt for id 5
setting rtt for id 6
setting rtt for id 7
setting rtt for id 8
setting rtt for id 9
setting rtt for id 10
setting rtt for id 11
setting rtt for id 12
setting rtt for id 13
setting rtt for id 14
setting rtt for id 15
[{1 10.10.10.0 2000000000} {2 10.10.10.1 2000000000} {3 10.10.10.2 4000000000} {4 10.10.10.3 1000000000} {5 10.10.10.4 3000000000} {6 10.10.10.5 0} {7 10.10.10.0 0} {8 10.10.10.1 1000000000} {9 10.10.10.2 0} {10 10.10.10.3 4000000000} {11 10.10.10.4 1000000000} {12 10.10.10.5 2000000000} {13 10.10.10.0 4000000000} {14 10.10.10.1 3000000000} {15 10.10.10.2 4000000000} {16 10.10.10.3 1000000000}]
```

Comment: Also note the change to the range, using an index instead of a range variable - the range variable will be made dynamically (copied), and changing that will just change the loop variable, rather than the member of the slice. I am probably not explaining this well, but it is a big gotcha.

Comment: Doesn't matter what do you put on channel? ```semaphore <- struct{}{}```

Comment: Nope, but doing an empty struct is kind of nice memory size-wise, but a bool would be ok there too.

Comment: Thank you for explain! I though channel served only to pass information between goroutines